pythonanywhere server shutdown automatically
What should I do to keep my bot running all the time?
I've created a telegram bot and host it on "python anywhere" (free plan). When I run it in the morning everything is ok, but when I want to use the bot after a couple of hours, it doesn't work, and I have to log in to my "python anywhere" account and hit the run again.

This solution may not meet your specific needs, but I have had a great experience with Cloudflare Workers. I have a Telegram bot running on them for over a year, and it is still running without any issues.

Are you running your code in a console? It won't keep running indefinitely because our console servers are regularly rebooted. If you've got a long running job we've got always-on tasks for that (a paid feature): https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/

Unfortunately, I'm using free version so can't do it.
Is there any other way?
